# Getting "null" when executing a HTTPPost on Android

Tags: android, node.js, http, post

I have a simple android app, and a NodeJS server, i have the following permissions on the android app manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And i'm trying to do a HTTP Post on a Local URL but it fails and gives me only `null` as error message, because of that, i dont know what to do.

Here is the code for the HTTP Post:

```java
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.25.32:8080/signup");
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams(); //i was using params, now i use valuepairs         
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Teste2"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "testezin@email.com"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", "Brazil"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "teste"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "123456"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));            
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post); //here goes to the Exception
```

What i'm doing wrong?

**Obs:** when acessing `http://192.168.25.32:8080/signup` i have a sign up form working perfectly with these params that i am setting on the HTTP Post, so you can assume that the NodeJS server is running and working properly.

Comment: What happened with params?

Comment: what params? the pair's are not the params?